# output from constructor in php issue

Tags: php, zend-framework

The output returned by the function when called from constructor is an object and not the array which its supposed to display. Below is an idea of my code. Please note that this is not my actual code. I'm just trying to give a basic idea of the functionality.

```
class Foo(){
    public function __construct($arg)
    {
        $this->A($arg);
    }

    public function A($arg)
    {
        $data = 2*$arg;
        return $data
    }
}

$obj = new Foo(10);
echo $obj;
```

I have been researching and found that constructor will return the instance of the object and not a value. If this is true, is there any workaround? I know I can use init() of Zend but I'm not too familiar with it. Any suggestions? Thank you for all your help in advance.

Comment: A is the function name. I'm calling A from __construct.

Answer (score 0):

create a property of the class

```
class Foo(){

    public var $myvar;

    public function __construct($arg)
    {
        $this->A($arg);
    }

    public function A($arg)
    {
        $this->myvar = 2*$arg;

    }
}

$obj = new Foo(10);
echo $this->myvar;
```

the problem you are having is $obj is the object created by your class.  when you return from the constructor it does nothing.   And echo'ing your class object isn't gong to do anything either.   You can also use ..

```
public function A($arg)
{
    $data = 2*$arg;
    echo $data;
}
```

if you want to just display it right there.   Then using

```
$obj = new Foo(10)
```

will be all you need to use to display the value.

Have a look here for more info on constructors.  Again, constructors do not return anything, they are for instancing the object only.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php